# Intermittent generic error occurred in GDI+ when saving image

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I built a dynamic image resizing web application in ASP.NET 4.0, and it is running on a Windows 2008 R2 server using IIS 7.5.

The images themselves are stored in a SQL 2008 R2 database as a binary max field (the images are small enough that this is feasible, and we initially tried the filestream option, but it was too slow for our purposes)

I query the database to retrieve the "blob" as a byte array and load it into an image object as follows:

```
Dim imageOriginal as Image = Nothing
Dim imageResized as Image = Nothing

imageOriginal = FindOriginalImage()
```

I need to do a few things to it - if it's a PNG, I have to draw it on a white canvas or I get some really crazy streaking if I need to resize the image.  I also potentially scale it down, maybe slap a watermark on it, and save it to disk before serving it up to the end user.  In order to do all of this I found that I had to create a second image object in order do some of the tasks necessary before saving it to disk, so I copied the original image into the resized object for processing. See below:

```
If Not imageOriginal is nothing then
    imageResized = imageOriginal
```

(The call to FindOriginalImage returns the value NOTHING if the image was not found in the database)

.... All the rest of the resizing, watermarking, etc - this code all works ...

After I do all that I need to do to the imageResized object, I then run this line:

```
imageResized.Save(DestinationFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Most of the time this works without a hitch, but occasionally I get a GDI+ generic error when I try to save the file to the disk.

Of course I dispose both objects after I am done with this too:

```
imageResized.Dispose()
imageOriginal.Dispose()
GC.Collect()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if you are overwriting the source file, you have to be sure you first dispose of the object which opened/locked the file.  A `Using` block will help

Comment: hmmm interesting - it is actually possible with how many requests coming in that more than one person could've triggered the code that "resizes" an image (it's a custom 404 handling page).  Once the image is created in the requested size, all future users will go right to it - so the code should never run again unless the resized version is deleted.  I will investigate this - given the infrequent occurrance, this is probably the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to save image to MemoryStream first, then dump the memory stream to file system - at least you can rule out file/access issues.

Comment: I like this answer.  I will try it and let you know if I still see it.

Comment: Still seeing the error, but at least I know exactly where it is happening now.  3 times in the last two hours, and it occurs at the point where I am trying to create the .JPG destination file on disk before I write out the memory stream.

Answer (score 1):

Generically speaking a "GDI+ generic error" usually is due to a file system permission issue.  Check to make sure the context under which the application pool is running has the appropriate  "write" permission to the folder in which you are trying to save.

Comment: Permissions are set properly for the identity being used by the Application pool, and we have verified this. It usually works but occasionally we get an odd glitch like this - could it be caused by the filesystem being overloaded? A lot of people are making requests - well over 200,000 a day, and I usually see less than 100 of these.